# angular.js ui-router pass variable to state url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass parameters to a state in angular.js ui-router like the following:

```
.state('details', {
    url: '/details/:index',
    templateUrl: 'views/details.html'
})
```

The index is being passed through an ng-repeat index

```
 <div ng-repeat="program in programs">
            <h2>{{program.name}}</h2>

            <p>{{program.description || "No Description"}}</p>

            <p><a ui-sref="details({index: $index})">View details »</a></p>
 </div>
```

my question is how in details.html do i read the index passed in the url of the state?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inject [**$stateParams**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) in your controller.

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8p55FoKIFHZFcvleFANe?p=preview).

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1/2")

  $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1/:index",
        templateUrl: "route1.html",
        controller: function($stateParams, $scope) {
            $scope.index = $stateParams.index 
        }
    })
    .state('route2', {
        url: "/route2",
        templateUrl: "route2.html"
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot @matys84pl , seems exactly what i have been looking for